# Fabric JS group selection and scaling messing up individual object position attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to achieve a function so that every object on the canvas scales down in size equally and center them on the canvas (in order to add some space / padding around the canvas)

However as soon as I define the `selection` variable, the position of the object completely changes, without changing position visually. Most `top` and `left` attributes become negative, I found out that their new position represent their distance from the **center** of the group of objects.

This causes persistent effects on the canvas, when I call `selection.addWithUpdate()` the bounding box appears in the same place, but the object controls (resize and rotation dots) are still on the incorrect position. I tried using `selection.setCoords()` to reset the controls, but it had no effect.

When I loop through every object and `console.log` the `obj.left` and `obj.top` I get the mostly negative values, as previously mentioned, i.e. the position of the object controls.

```
var selection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(canvas.getObjects(), { canvas: canvas });
selection.scaleToHeight(0.8)
selection.center();

canvas.renderAll()
selection.addWithUpdate()
selection.setCoords()
```

[image]

Comment: Please add Codesandbox with minimum code to replicate the issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the coordinates go into the negative is that the selection thinks `(0, 0)` is the **center of the selection**. You have probably seen values like this on your objects:

[image]

Adding the `left` and `top` attributes of the selection itself to the object calculates to the original position. Something simple like this is all you need:

```js
function calculateOriginalPosition(selection) {
  selectionObjects = selection.getObjects();

  selectionObjects.forEach((object) => {
    // Giving each object the original position.
    object.left += selection.left;
    object.top += selection.top;

    // Do something with your object here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="qwery-bonzo-bean.js"></script>
    <script src="qbb-config.js"></script>
    <script src="fabric-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <button id="mobilePortrait" data-scale="320px,480px">320x480</button>
        <button id="mobileLandscape" data-scale="480px,320px">480x320</button>
  
        <button id="tabletPortrait" data-scale="768px,1024px">768x1024</button>
        <button id="tabletLandscape" data-scale="1024px,768px">1024x768</button>
  
        <button id="fullscreen" data-scale="100%,100%">100%</button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewport">
        <div id="content">
        <div id="map">
            <div id="bg" class="scalable"><img src="http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/building-and-sky-wallpapers_575_1024x768.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
            <div id="canvi">
                <canvas id="draw_canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="viewportBorder"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```